# Searching for a color tag in html (Python 3)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab elements from a table if a cell has a certain color. Only issue is that for the color tags, grabbing the color does not seem possible just yet.

```
jump = []

for tr in site.findAll('tr'):
  for td in site.findAll('td'):
    if td == 'td bgcolor':
      jump.append(td)

print(jump)
```

This returns an empty list

How do I grab just the color from the below html?

I need to get the color from the [td] tag (it would also be useful to get the color from the [tr] tag)

```
<tr bgcolor="#f4f4f4">
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;CME_ES&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:46&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;Connected&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;07:58:00&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP" bgcolor="#55aa2a">&nbsp;--:--:--&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp;01:25:00 &nbsp;</td>
<td height="25" nowrap="NOWRAP">&nbsp; 22:00:00&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is **site**?

Comment: @mkam I cannot share entire site (it is confidential to company) but I can provide any snippets of html necessary to get solution

Comment: I meant, what type of object is the variable **site**.

Comment: Ahh,  **site** is a beautifulsoup object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
jump = []

for tr in site.findAll('tr'):
  for td in site.findAll('td'):
    if 'bgcolor' in td.attrs:
      #jump.append(td)
      print(td.attrs['bgcolor'])

print(jump)
```

Comment: Excellent! Worked as needed!

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`has_attr`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to check if an element has a certain attribute:

```
if td.has_attr('bgcolor'):
    jump.append(td)
```

If i misread your answer and you want to only find `td`s of a certain color, use [`find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):

```
tr.find_all("td", {"bgcolor": "55aa2a"}) # returns list of matches
```

---

PS: if someone has a better docs snippet for `has_attr`, please edit this answer.

Comment: No it's fine. The conditional you provided populated with exactly what I needed. It found every color in document. But I like the idea you have there of finding specific colors